# PHP / calling a function from a class from a different file

Tags: php, function, class

I have to write two php files. 
The first one has to hold the main class with the functions and the second one should just call the function from the first file (main.php).

```
main.php
<?php
class main {
    public function parseCSV(....

parse.php
<?php
include('main.php');
echo"<pre>";
print_r(parseCSV());
echo"</pre>";
```

If I put the function and the echo in one file, it works perfectly. 
Hopefully you will understand my question and maybe you can give me a hint.

Comment: that's a method. you haven't instantiated the object it's in, and that's not how you call methods either. `$foo = new main(); $foo->parseCSV();`

Answer (score 3):

You don't have initiated the object and that's not even how you call methods/functions from the object...

Try this!
**Parse.php**

```
<?php
include("main.php");

$object = new main();

echo "<pre">;
print_r($object->parseCSV());
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I was answering while somebody else posted his answer. So I add just this.
Another possibility would be to declare the method as static. So the file main.php would become:

```
<?php
class main {
    public static function parseCSV(....
```

Then you should be able to call the method like this:

```
parse.php
<?php 
    include_once('main.php');
    echo"<pre>";
    print_r(main::parseCSV());
    echo"</pre> ...
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks a lot. I would like to invite you to a beer^^

Answer (score 0):

You defined a class in the main.php file, so if you want to use the method of this class you'll have to instantiate it. Something like this should work:

```
parse.php
<?php 
include_once('main.php');
$m=new main();
echo"<pre>";
print_r($m->parseCSV());
echo"</pre>";
```

Another possibility would be to declare the method as static. So the file
main.php would become:

```
<?php
class main {
    public static function parseCSV(....
```

Then you should be able to call the method like this:

```
parse.php
<?php 
include_once('main.php');
echo"<pre>";
print_r(main::parseCSV());
echo"</pre> ...
```

Hope this is usefull...

Comment: I think `main m = new main();` will not work for certain reasons.

Comment: Sure it was a typo, I clearly meant $m=new main(); thanks